# How can I find out which Opportunities, Leads, or Accounts have not been viewed recently?

Tags: soap-api

The Account, Lead, and Opportunity objects all have the fields (LastViewedDate and LastReferencedDate) that return when the object was last viewed or referenced - by the calling user.  So, if I ran a query against Opportunity that queried records that have LastViewedDate < (today - 90 days), I would be getting the opportunities that have not been viewed for 90 days by the calling user.

What if I want to run this type of query and return Opportunities that have not been viewed by ANY users for the past 90 days?

Answer (score 2):

From everything I've found that object is limited to the current running user. Notes from the doc [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_referencepre/Content/sforce_api_objects_recentlyviewed.htm):

> This object provides a heterogeneous list of different object types
>   and consists of recently viewed records or records that were recently
>   referenced (a related record was viewed). A record is considered
>   viewed when the user sees the details associated with it, but not when
>   the user sees it in a list with other records. Use this object to
>   programmatically construct a list of recently viewed items specific to
>   the **current user**, for example, on a custom user interface or for
>   search auto-complete options. You can also retrieve a filtered list of
>   records by object type (Type). The RecentlyViewed data is periodically
>   truncated down to 200 records per object.

Also from a blog on the release [here](http://www.verticalcoder.com/2013/04/29/salesforce-summer-13-developer-features/):
It states that "You can't query what another user has viewed".

Comment: Its possible that he might be able to run a report on it, especially if he were to bucket all of the users. The results would still be very limited in scope.